# NRF24L01+ Power Amplifier -dBm options to milliWatt

Tags: arduino, rf, radio, nrf24l01

> From the datasheet for these module I have the folowing power settings
>   available (listed form highest to lowest), I need to know what they equate to in milliwatt, as in
>   Australia maximum 2.4ghz power I can use is 10mw.

RF output power - DC current consumption

0dBm - 11.3mA

-6dBm - 9.0mA

-12dBm - 7.5mA

-18dBm - 7.0mA

*Conditions: VDD = 3.0V, VSS = 0V, T A  = 27ºC, Load impedance = 15Ω+j88Ω*

**Thanks**

**Edit:** Is it possible that the dbm value above is relative to total max power output. so 0 is uninhibited, and -6dbm is taking away 6dbm from full. in this case i think it may be 20dbm (100mw)

**Edit:** Photos Added of device: [image: Top][image: Bottom]

Comment: 0dBm is 1mW (that's what it's referenced to) so they're all below that. This wouldn't make an appropriate answer in itself but there's a few online calculators like this one http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/power/dBm_to_mW.htm

Comment: Note that those are power *consumption* numbers whereas the regulatory limit is *output* power, much lower.

Comment: @pjc50 I don't understand, the table above lists the dBm values as RF output power, why do you say they are consumption numbers and not output power?

Comment: I thought you were trying to use the current consumption numbers as a measure of power, which you aren't, sorry.

Comment: no i wasnt sorry, it was just in the datasheet, 0dbm i believe is the wost powerfull setting though i thought from the data sheet, and i read the max output 60mw

Comment: The board you have has a external power-amp on the nRF. As such, the nRF's power numbers are no longer valid.

Comment: @ConnorWolf, yes bet they still effect the output level and are the only software way to do so.

Comment: @HaydenThring - This is true, but I think you should think of them as power level 1, 2, 3, 4, etc..., rather then in terms of dBm, because that will put you on a better basis to start from .

Answer (score 4):

The classic formula for converting power between dBm and mW is

$$ P[dBm]=10log_{10} \frac{P[mW]} {1mW} $$

To convert in the other direction, you use formula:
$$ P[mW]=10^{\frac{P[dBm]}{10}}$$

Few handy things to know is that for every 3 dB, power increases around two times and for every 10 dB, power increases 10 time, so for example 10 mW is 10 dBm, 100 mW is 20 dBm, 1W is 30 dBm = 1 dBW and so on.

Also keep in mind that you can add togetherunits in dB and dBm, so if you have output power of say 0 dBm and connect that to a 10 dB amplifier, you'd get 0 dBm + 10 dB = 10 dBm output power.

Comment: thanks for that last bit, it supports my current theory. here it says the PA is 20db and its max out put is 20dbm, so the setting im talking about reduces the total output by that settings negative dbm value. http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=2.4G_Wireless_nRF24L01p_with_PA_and_LNA#Specification

Comment: @Hayden Thring I don't think so. I'm reading the datasheet now and in the section where they talk about the amplifier, it says:`The PA (Power Amplifier) control is used to set the output power from the nRF24L01+ power amplifier.` Later on in the register description section, they talk about same set of power levels. Furthermore, at the beginning of the document, they say again `Programmable output power: 0, -6, -12 or -18dBm` In the Transmitter operation section, the typical maximum power is said to be 0 dBm with +4 dBm being the maximum. I think that those are numbers going to the antenna.

Comment: @Hayden Thring One thing that may be worth checking is if in your local regulations, antenna's gain is taken into account when determining the power. If it is, in the worst case, when the module's own power reading is off by +4 dBm and you have additional 2 dBi gain, you'd still have +6 dBm in the direction of the module's strongest radiation, which is under the +10 dBm limit.

Comment: antenna gain is taken into consideration i thought here in australia. the antenna is currently 2 db i believe. when you say under the limit. you are assuming 0dbm is 1mw  ? well these units have much more power than that and are claimed to reach 1km, and max power 20dbm on some sites (100mw)

Comment: @Hayden Thring Well by definition 0 dBm is 1 mW. I really don't see any way in the datasheet that the output power can be set to +20 dBm. That is only written on the wiki page. After looking at the schematic, I can't see any active external component on it, so I conclude that there must be a mistake in the wiki. The 1 km figure is reachable even with 0 dBm transmit power.

Comment: @Hayden Thring If you for example take the specification for receive power with data rate of  250 kb/s which is -94 dBm, use 0 dBm at the transmitter side and two 3 dBi or 4 dBi antennas, using [Friis free space formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation), you can easily reach the distance of around 1 km. IF you think that the output power can be set to be higher, please provide were exactly you saw that.

Comment: see here: http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=2.4G_Wireless_nRF24L01p_with_PA_and_LNA#Specification

Comment: @Hayden Thring Yes, I saw that, but I suspect that is is wrong. I can't see any obvious way to actually set that value in chip's configuration. Furthermore looking at the schematic of the module, there is noting to further amplify the output of the chip. Looking at the chip's datasheet, there is nothing that indicates that it can support +20 dBm output.

Comment: there is a power amplifier chip on some models and not on others: with:http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/141090082049?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649 without: http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/NRF24L01-Wireless-Transceiver-Module-SMA-Antenna-Microcontroll-Arduino-2-4G-/350916012373?pt=AU_B_I_Electrical_Test_Equipment&hash=item51b4396955

Comment: @Hayden Thring That could very well be the case, but the module you linked, according to its schematic, to does not have an external power amplifier. Do you have the actual module itself? If so, please post a clear, focused picture of the both sides of the PCB such that witing on devices is visible. I there is an external power amplifier, I should be able to identify it.

Comment: thankyou for your help ! i have added photos to opening post

Comment: @Hayden Thring Well I can now definitely say that the schematic in the zip file at the bottom of the wiki article is for a different product. I should have noticed that immediately, but I didn't take a good look at the layout jpg until just now. In any case, I must take back the claim that there is nom external power amplifier. There is and it's [RFaxis RFX2401C](http://www.rfaxis.com/our_products/rfx2401.php). It has small-signal gain of 28 dB.

Comment: @Hayden Thring I can't currently see how they got the +20 dBm value from the power amplifier, but I suspect that it could ahve something to do with the `TX Output P1dB` value which I haven't used previously, so I'm not sure I understand it correctly. Anyway to get back to the power calculation. You can select one of the offered power options for the main chip. That power is that increased by the gain of the RFX2401C. The output is then increased by the antenna.

Comment: @Hayden Thring So if you set the 0 dBm at the Nordic chip and add the RFX's amplification of 28 dB (which needs to be checked) and add to that the 2 dBi gain from the antenna, you get some 30 dBm of power in the direction of the strongest radiation, which is 100 times the allowed power limit. Even if the gain of the amplifier was 20, you'd still have 22 dBm, which is almost 16 times the allowed power. The result is that if you want to comply with your regulations, you need to set the Nordic chip to either -12 dBm or -18 dBm.

Comment: yes, thanks. this is along the lines that i was thinking. if it is 20dbm gain then i can use -12dbm setting with 2db antenna and i should have 10db which is 10mw

Comment: do you want to edit your answer, and i will accept it

Answer (score 2):

You can read *N dBm* as *N dB above 1 mW*
e.g.

0 dBm = 0 dB above 1 mW = 1mW
20 dBm = 20 dB above 1 mW = 100 mW etc.

Now, the power settings you discussed in your question belong to NRF24L01. This setting controls output power level of NRF24L01 only, not the module.

The actual transmit power of module depends on the features of frontend IC also, which is X2401C. As per its datasheet, it provides 25dB gain upto saturation power of 22dBm

[image: RFA X2401C datasheet power and gain]

Simply put, this means that X2401C will add 25 dB to NRF24L01's output power upto a maximum output of 22 dBm.

so for 4 settings in NRF chip, corresponding typical output power would be:
+22 dBm, ~158 mW
+19 dBm, ~80 mW
+13 dBm, ~20 mW
+7 dBm, ~5 mW

respectively.

Note:
(1) Around saturated power, amplifiers are not linear. This may or may not matter for digital transmissions, perhaps someone else can comment on that.
(2) Power, gain, and saturated power in those data sheets are typical values. Some variation should be expected between individual pieces.
(3) There will be some losses every where.

Answer (score 1):

0 dBm is generally regarded as 1 milli-watt and power halves approximately every 3 dB (3.0103 dB to be more exact). Can you work the rest out for your self?

Comment: "generally regarded"? How about "explicitly defined"?

Comment: Yeah that too LOL

Comment: 0dbm i believe is the wost powerfull setting though i thought from the data sheet, and i read the max output 60mw